# How to show php login errors?

Tags: php

I'm working on a simple login system to improve my knowledge and I would like to know how I can show alert messages if user type the wrong password or username or he doesn't fill any fields, I've started with something but I'm not sure if it is the right way and I don't know how to show message in the page with the login form. Many thanks for your help :)

**This is my login controller**

```
<?php
/**
 * Nome File : ctrl_login.php
 * Descrizione: File che gestisce i dati inseriti nella pagina di login
 */

include('../config/konasi.php');
include('functions.php');

$user_name   = check_input($_POST['username']);
$user_password = check_input($_POST['userpassword']);

if (!$user_name || !$user_password) {
    echo "Non hai inserito username o password";
    exit();
}

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT user_password FROM users WHERE user_name= ? ")) {
    /* Bind parameters: s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
    $stmt -> bind_param("s", $user_name);
    /* Execute it */
    $stmt -> execute();
    /* Bind results */
    $stmt -> bind_result($result);
    /* Fetch the value */
    $stmt -> fetch();
    /* Close statement */
    $stmt -> close();
}

if(password_verify($user_password, $result)) {    
    echo "you are connected!";    
} else {        
    echo "Ops, wrong password";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

**This is my index file with the login form**

```
<form class="form-signin" action="includes/ctrl_login.php" method="post">
    <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Login </h3>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username </label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="userpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

**This is my function.php**

```
function check_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: You have many possibilities. On `ctrl_login.php` you can redirect the user to the form login and pass the errors inside the querystring ( like `your_form_page.php?errors=Non hai inserito username o password` ), then show message where you want. That's a primarily opinion-based question, really. Choose what's best for you. Ciao.

Comment: Ciao Federkun many thanks for your answer. I'll try it and let you know ;) grazie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the way is to set session variable in your controller and redirect them to login page then show them in your login page.

put folloing line above your both login page and controller.

```
session_start();
```

add following line in your login form page

```
<p><?=$_SESSION['error_msg']?></p>
```

in your controller instead of echo message set them in session variable. such as

```
$_SESSION['error_msg'] = 'Ops, wrong password';
header("location: link_to_login_form");
exit();
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Reza many thanks for your support i did manage to pass the error message using sessions. Now i would like to create a redirect using session so if user is admin will go to admin dashboard and if is client will go to client dashboard. I've created a new table in the database and i called it user_role where i can set in int of 1 or 0 could you help me?

Comment: After successful authentication. Check user role from database. Then put if(user == 'admin') header("location:admin.php"); else header("location:user.php");

Answer (score -1):

Simply use this function to check login:

```
function login_check($username,$pwd){

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`=? AND `user_password`=? ")) {
        /* Bind parameters: s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
        $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $user_name,,$pwd);
        /* Execute it */
        $stmt -> execute();
        /* Bind results */
        $stmt -> bind_result($result);
        /* Fetch the value */
        $login_row=$stmt -> fetch();

        if($login_row[0]>=1) {
            echo "You are connected";
        } else {
            echo "Ops, wrong password";
        }

        /* Close statement */
        $stmt -> close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi Sarath many thanks for your answer. I read in a php book i shouldn't use variables into the SELECT query to avoid SQL injections. Also if i use this function can i show the message into the page where the login form is? This is a different file from the php controller

Comment: The difference here to the OP's code, is that it looks as if the OP hashes their user passwords with Php's password_hash.  And therefore is retrieving a row and verifying the password.  That's fine.  This code looks as if the password is unhashed, or you have to generate the hash first.  mysqli_stmt::fetch returns true, false or null.  Not a row.  Not sure what you are doing there. or with your mysql_stmt::bind_param.  Hence this answer is quite useless.